# New user account that only differs in a single upper case letter

Tags: discussion, accounts

I was quite surprised when I saw that I (well, not really) asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70092220) until I realized that the user asking that, is named **A**_horse_with_no_name - but my account uses a lower case **a**.

While I (think) I understand the technical reason behind this, I wonder why this is allowed. It seems, this could be a source of possible confusion.

Comment: Usernames are not unique. Even with the same case.

Comment: I assume we would run out of viable usernames pretty quickly if "similar enough" usernames were blocked.

Comment: If you have a reason to think someone is impersonating you on purpose (such as imitating underscores in a username where spaces are allowed), especially when it's combined with other unwanted behavior, you can consider a modflag, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: We, unfortunately, have had some recent issues with newly-created troll accounts attempting to imitate existing, established users, going so far as to copy not only their display names but also their profile pictures and sometimes even other information. Obviously, attempting to pass yourself off as *being* another user is not OK, and especially not if it is done out of bad faith. This doesn't appear (yet) to be a case like that, but if so, or if you're seeing something I haven't, then please do raise a flag for moderator attention on one of the user's posts.

Comment: @CodyGray: OK, will do. Thanks

Comment: Did you adopt that name because SO is a good-question desert?

Comment: Both users could pretty much enjoy the desert song by America.